# India death records from c.1947?

Tags: 20th-century, death-records, india

I have a relative who lived in India later in life but am struggling to identify exactly when he died.

He was British but was in Punjab, India by 1911 (he appears on the UK 1911 census as he was in the army). He married in Bombay (Mumbai) in 1922, and his children were born in India and he appears to have spent much of the rest of his life there.

I am told he died in roughly 1946 or 1947 in India, but unsure where. I have searched FamilySearch's [India Deaths and Burials, 1719-1948](https://www.familysearch.org/search/collection/1584968), as well as the [British Overseas Deaths](https://search.findmypast.co.uk/search-world-Records/british-armed-forces-and-overseas-deaths-and-burials). Cannot find any mention searching both [British](https://www.britishnewspaperarchive.co.uk/) and [Australian](https://trove.nla.gov.au/) newspapers (he had family in Australia as well).

Not knowing where in India is certainly hindering the search process. Most likely it was in the northwest of modern India (Rajasthan, Punjab, possibly as far south as Mumbai) but that still doesn't narrow it down much.

Any suggestions as to where to search next?

Comment: I'm guessing you are already familiar with [FIBIS](https://www.fibis.org/)?  If not, they have a database, wiki and other resources that might help provide some pointers.

Comment: @sempaiscuba Yes, thanks - meant to add that I had looked there. Most of the FIBIS databases seem to cover the 19th century or earlier.